# Create a method to return the the WC complement of a DNA strand

Tags: java

Okay so I'm asked to create a method complementWC() which works like this:

```
public String complementWC()
```

*Returns the Watson Crick complement, which is a string representing the complementary DNA strand (i.e., the other strand in the double helix). So swap all T’s with A’s, all A’s with T’s, all C’s with G’s and all G’s with C’s.*

And this is what I managed to do:

```
private String dna;

    public String complementWC(){
        String dnaWC = "";
        for(int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
            if(dna.charAt(i) == 'T'){
                dna.replace(dna.charAt(i), 'A');
            }
            if(dna.charAt(i) == 'A'){
                dna.replace(dna.charAt(i), 'T');
            }
            if(dna.charAt(i) == 'C'){
                dna.replace(dna.charAt(i), 'G');
            }
            if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
                dna.replace(dna.charAt(i), 'C');
            }   
            dnaWC = dna;
        }
        return dnaWC;
    }
```

Now, the problem is that this method just returns the original dna instead of the WCcomplement. So, I'm not sure how to store the String inside the for loop into a new string called 'dnaWC'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  When you call `replace`, it is returning a new string, not changing the original string, and you promptly ignore the returned string.  That is why your original string never got changed.

You can build a new string with `StringBuilder`, which would save the overhead of creating a new string each time a character is replaced, as only one new string will be created.

```
public String complementWC(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
        char c = dna.charAt(i);
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'T'){
            builder.append('A');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'A'){
            builder.append('T');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'C'){
            builder.append('G');
        }
        if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
            builder.append('T');
        }   
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I see. But is there a way to use the replace function and then store the new string in 'dnaWC'?

Comment: Sure, you could use the replace method and store the new string in `dnaWC`.  You would be creating a new String object each time, it's up to you if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

The complement of `G` is `C` (not `T`). So it should be...

```
 if(dna.charAt(i) == 'G'){
        builder.append('C');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String complementWC(String dna) {
    char[] chars = dna.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = getComplement(chars[i]);
    }

    return new String(chars);
}

private static char getComplement(char c) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'A': return 'T';
        case 'T': return 'A';
        case 'C': return 'G';
        case 'G': return 'C';
    }

    return c;
}
```